# Given the distribution function of a continous random variable $X$...

Tags: probability, statistics

Given the distribution function of a continous random variable $X$:

$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & x<0 \\
cx^2+x/2, &0<=x<1 \\
1, &x>=1\
\end{cases}$

Is $c=9/4$?

How can I find the probability density of $X$? And what is its graph?

Comment: a CDF is continuous so $F(1^-) = F(1^+)$. Use that to find $c$.

Comment: I'm guessing you integrated the middle range and tried to fit it to $F(1) = 1$; that isn't appropriate since $F$ is a distribution function, not a density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the random variable is continuous $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$ whence the d.f is continuous everywhere. In particular this means that
$$
1=\lim_{y\uparrow 1} F(y)=c+\frac{1}{2}
$$
so $c=1/2$. To find the density just differentiate the distribution function and note that $X\in[0, 1]$ w.p.1.